# use fractal to decode from array to custom PHP object

Tags: php, thephpleague-fractal

using League/fractal, i am attempting to transform data from array to my PHP object...in the following way

```
final class StatusDeserializer extends AbstractTransformer
{


    public function transform(Status $status)
    {
        return new StatusObject(
            $status['name'],
            $status['message']
        );
    }
}
```

my object definition

```
final class StatusObject
{

    private $name;
    private $message;

    public function __construct($name, $message)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->message = $message;
    }
}
```

test implementation here

```
$data = [ 'name' => 'foo', 'message' => 'bar' ]
$this->fractalManager->createData($data, new StatusDeserializer());
```

But i get this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to League\Fractal\Scope::filterFieldsets() must be of the type array, object given
```

#### Edit 1

I tried wrapping the array into Fractals collection,  i.e

```
$data = new Collection([ 'name' => 'foo', 'message' => 'bar' ]);
```

and it now returns an instance of `League\Fractal\Scope` instead of my StatusObject instance

### Edit 2

Adding ->toArray() brought me back to the first error

```
$this->fractalManager->createData($data, new StatusDeserializer())->toArray();
```

see screen shot : https://gmkr.io/s/5a0b755c683d0d77313ff0fa/0

Answer (score 1):

`FractalManager` wants an instance of `ResourceInterface` as first argument. So you just want to change your code like this

```
$data = new Collection([ 'name' => 'foo', 'message' => 'bar' ]);
$this->fractalManager->createData($data, new StatusDeserializer());
```

Comment: still does not work...i even tried `new Item([ 'name' => 'foo', 'message' => 'bar' ]);`

Comment: actually , it does work when i applied your suggestion, but it returns an instance of `League\Fractal\Scope` instead of my object...any ideas?

Comment: `Scope` has an `toArray` method, which does the actual transformation.

Comment: when i added ->toArray()...i got the first error again..see screen shothttps://gmkr.io/s/5a0b755c683d0d77313ff0fa/0